# How can I modeling these case more efficiently?

Tags: modeling

[image]
I tried modeling as shown above.
I separated the edge and moved the 3d cursor and origin. I also used multiple snaps and joined the edges back into their original objects to create faces.
I got the results I wanted, but I felt my process was a bit complicated.
The GIF below is a summary of my process.

[image]

[image]

The extrude region vertex normals (Alt + E) function is close to the operation I want, but it does not produce a flat surface if it carves out the interior.
Probably there seems to be a modeling technique I'm missing. If you have ideas for a faster process, please let me know.

And i attach the blend file for the convenience of the respondent who will show the example.
Thanks for your attention.

[image]

Comment: One way could probably be copying edges of the original object profile, separating them and turning into a curve, with bevel object you can create indent from the curve like on the end result. Then use Boolean to cut it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way seems pretty sensible to me, but just in case this way introduces a couple of useful add-ons...

[image]

- Delete the bottom front Ngon, and <kbd>I</kbd> inset the remaining front and top faces as a region, with 'Boundary' unchecked, to prevent a margin being formed at the mirror axis, or against the empty face.

[image]

- Delete the inset faces

[image]

- Having switched on 'Lengths' in the Property region > Mesh Display panel, take a note of the width the offset will have to be from the marked selected edges
- Use the shipped Mesh:'Offset Edges' add-on > 'Extrude' to extrude the front edges back by that width, numerically entered.
- There may be some overlapping vertices on the new inner edges of the cluster of loops on the short rear-facing slope. Select the problematic range of vertices and use the shipped add-on 'Loop Tools' > 'Space' to make them regular. ( I went back to make those loops regular all the way round )

[image]

- <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> the offset edges to the mirror axis, letting the 'Clip' of the mirror modifier do its work
- <kbd>F</kbd> Fill the Ngon we removed in the first place
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> >  <kbd>R</kbd> remove doubles.

This may well be one of those places where a Boolean is a snappier way of doing it, as Mr Zak has commented .. I'm unreasonably resistant to using Booleans.

Comment: amazing!
I did not even know that boundary unchecking and offset edges add-on existed. Now I can model faster.
But after I tried the way you introduced it, there was one more question.
I would like to follow up on another modeling technique in the link below.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135629/vertex-slide-and-snap-not-working-together